# Creating a .net webservice stub with xml storage

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, code-generation

I've been asked to come up with a .net web service stub for multiple similar webservices which will:

- implement create/read/update/delete/find for an arbitrary object.
- hold persistent xml data for objects of that type.

Is there anything out there that does this job already or anything that can make the job of creating it easier?

Comment: Is the CRUD against the XML persistent store?

Answer (score 0):

You may look at [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx). As usual with Microsoft products it is impossible to understand what it really does by looking at the front page, but is something of a "query a database by specifying the query in the URL in a standardized format (OData)". It creates a WCF service as a front end, and you should be able to write your own dataprovider for XML files.

It is arbitrary in the sense that the technology is independent of the object type, but you need to create a schema for its specific datatypes.